# Convert 01010 string in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

How can I convert "000000111111111110000000000000000000000001111111" into an array of numbers like [0,0,0,...,1,1].

I have tried without success:

```
eval('[' + string + ']')
```

and

```
JSON.parse('[' + string + ']')
```

Comment: Loop through them and push them to an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through string with `for` and push each number to the array:

```
var ar = [] 
for(var i=0; i< string.length;i++)
  ar.push(string[i] * 1)
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/houxvdjw/)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work.

```
var a = [];
var s = "000000111111111110000000000000000000000001111111";
for(var i=0; i<s.length; i++)
{
    a.push(parseInt(s[i],10));
}
```

Comment: `parseInt` should have a radix and split is unnecessary.

Comment: I had a typo in there... I had `parseInt(a[i],10)` instead of `parseInt(s[i],10)`

Answer (score 1):

Use the `String.split()` method.

```
var str = "000000111111111110000000000000000000000001111111";
var arr = str.split("");

for (num in arr){
    num = Number(num);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the string as a character array, and you can use the + to convert the string into an int.

```
var str = "110100010010011000101010101001";

var arr = [];
for(var idx in str)
  arr.push(+str[idx]);   

// proof
console.log(arr);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4v5qysnv/

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop to iterate over each character or split the string. Once you've broken it down, you need to convert each element to a number using `parseInt` (make sure to include a radix).

```js
var data = "000000111111111110000000000000000000000001111111";
var nums = data.split('').map(function(it) {
  return parseInt(it, 10);
});

document.getElementById('results').textContent = JSON.stringify(nums);
```

```html
<pre id="results"></pre>
```

If you want, you can use `filter` after the `map` to remove any elements that are not `0` or `1`.